# How do I redirect an old style post to a new URL format?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website that is going to  be converted to  a new cms. The reason for doing this is to not lose inbound links and end up with dead pages in search engines.

In the old website   the URLs are structured like:

```
website.com/4212/write-a-google-review
```

and in the new:

```
website.com/blog?write-a-google-review
```

although I have some flexibility in that I can add the ID into the URL string  as in any of:

```
website.com/blog?4212&write-a-google-review
website.com/blog?4212-write-a-google-review
website.com/blog?4212/write-a-google-review
website.com/blog?write-a-google-review&4212
```

I have tried a number of rewrite variations some just matching the  ID, others matching the text string, but haven't gotten the  right formula yet.

```
RewriteRule ^4212/?$ blog?4212/write-a-google-review [NC,L] ## 
RewriteRule ^[4212]?$ blog?4212/write-a-google-review [NC,L] ##
```

---

Comment added testing the 1st answer (by Croises).

As a singular redirect I found that this works but only if I gave the full url with https://www.mywebsite.com/:

```
RewriteRule write-a-google-review/?$ https://www.mywebsite.com/blog?write-a-google-review [NC,L]
```

When I added the following two lines it resulted in a broken page, no styling, no post content output:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(\d+(?:/.+?)?)/?$ blog?$1 [L]
```

So curious I changed it to  include the full url like the following and it worked as a regex solution for all entries:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(\d+(?:/.+?)?)/?$ http://www.mywebsite.com/blog?$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(\d+(?:/.+?)?)/?$ blog?$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thx - it works after I proceed the word blog with the full URL including https. I added a comment to the original post.

Comment: It's because you ask for redirection, not rewrite. I add the R=301 for that.

Comment: For the problem with css or pictures, add `<base href="/">` or path to the folder, in your html head.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)blog\?4212($|&)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)write-a-google-review($|&)
RewriteRule ^website\.com/index\.php$ /website.com/blog?4212-write-a-google-review&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

## From

```
website.com/index.php?blog?4212&write-a-google-review
```

## To

```
website.com/blog?4212-write-a-google-review
```

## Regex

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)?$ index.php?alias=$1\?$2\-$3 [L]

Array
(
    [alias] => blog?8753-lowering-expectations-with-skype
)
```